# How to use the @ sign in Azure Data Factory dynamic content when refering to a JSON key?

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

I have an ADF pipeline that loops through the pages of an API to store all the pages into a datalake. This pipeline needs to check the JSON of the last page it stored to see if there is a next API page it can retrieve.

I try to achieve this by creating a look-up activity to get the first row of the specific file. After getting the first row of the file, I want to check if the specific key that indicates whether there is a new API page exists.

So I created a 'set variable' activity with the following code:

```
@if(
  contains(
    activity('Get API Page').output.firstRow.odata.@odata.nextLink, 
    'nextRecordPosition'
  ), 
  string(
    activity('Get API Page').output.firstRow.odata.@odata.nextLink
    ), 'Done'
 )
```

This code would normally run fine, but not in this case. As you can see there is an @ sign in one (**@odata**) of the keys and ADF does not accept this.

Is there any way of escaping/replacing this character?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this issue appeared to be the following:

```
activity('Get API Page')['output']['firstRow']['@odata.nextLink']
```

Hopefully this helps anyone else.